# How to install Dbase in PHP 5.3.13

Tags: php, wampserver, dbase

I have a problem regarding on the dbase extension in PHP 5.3.13 .

My dbase_open can't recognize i think it's because of my extensions.

i uncomment this following extensions but it doesn't work

> extension = dba.dll 
>   extension = dblib.dll

Is there's anybody knows the solution for this.

Thank you and Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I believe the extension for Dbase database access is called dbase.dll.
The dll's you have activated are nothing to do with dbase.

You have to download the dbase extension via [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/dbase) and then put the dll into the `/ext` folder.
Then add

```
extension dbase.dll
```

to your php.ihi file